# how do I set my bot sending all the logs to a named channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
let logschannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel =\> channel.name === 'logs');
```

I want to get my bot to send logs from joining and leaving to deleting a message in a specifically named channel. Can someone help?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: No error, its just not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got one wrong code in your given code which is the `=\>` to do this you need to find first the channel, **yes, you do it right**. You just need to change `=\>` to `=>`.

Now when you finished changing that all you need to do is to call the `logschannel`

```
let logschannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'logs');
loschannel.send({content: "your content"})
```

can do with embeds too.

```
let logschannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'logs');
logschannel.send({embeds: [your_embed_name]});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change `=/>` to `=>`
And then, check this out:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/typedef/WSEventType

You would probably like to run your code with every guild event in the above docs link.